# Angular - Can InjectionToken be used with AOT Compilation?

Tags: angular, angular-aot

In my application a config object that is being injected from the window to the Angular application. To go about this I had developed something along these lines:

**Code**

*Model representing the config*

```
export class AppConfig {
    constructor(
        public apiKey: string,
        public username: string,
        public languageCode: string
    ) { }
}
```

*Creating an InjectionToken*

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { AppConfig } from './shared';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('appConfig');
```

*This is then provided in the AppModule*

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from './app-config-export';
....
@NgModule({
    ....
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: (window as any).appConfig }
})

export class AppModule { }
```

*Finally inject it in a component*

```
import { AppConfig } from '../shared';
import { APP_CONFIG} from './app-config-export';

....

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(
         @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: any,
         private appService: AppService
     ) { }

     ngOnInit() {
         this.appService.initApp(this.appConfig);
     }
}
```

**AOT Compilation**

This works fine, however now I've been trying to build the application using AOT compilation. When I run the application with AOT, the `appConfig` is always `null`. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm injecting the config which might not be compatible with AOT. Is there a way to get this to work with AOT?

I found this thread on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19154, however I'm not understanding what is meant by "use a factory instead".

- **Angular: 4.4.4**
- **Webpack: 3.8.1**

**Update**

I've updated the AppModule like so:

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from './app-config-export';
....

export function appConfigFactory() {
    return (window as any).appConfig;
}

@NgModule({
    ....
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useFactory: appConfigFactory() }
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Solution**

I've updated the AppModule like so:

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from './app-config-export';
....

export function appConfigFactory() {
    return (window as any).appConfig;
}

@NgModule({
    ....
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useFactory: appConfigFactory }
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I was calling the function in the `useFactory` callback instead of passing the function.

Comment: when and where do you set window.appConfig value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pankaj Parkar's solution is almost correct, but you also need to export the `useFactory` callback to allow AoT:

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from './app-config-export';

export function configFactory() {
  return (window as any).appConfig;
}

@NgModule({
  providers: {
    provide: APP_CONFIG,
    useFactory: configFactory,
  }
})
```

Otherwise you will run into this error:

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function...

Comment: I was about to write the same thing :) I just tried the code, however the config is now `undefined` instead of `null`

Comment: Where/when do you set `window.appConfig`? Sounds like it is just not there when you need it.

Comment: The config is being set before the angular application is loaded. I'm debugging the code and when I type in `window.appConfig` in the console I do have a value.

Comment: Well testing this live via `console` is not a good idea, as you are doing it after the problem occurred. Try putting some `console.log()` to the place where you set the value and then to the place where you try to read it (in the factory).

Comment: Yep you're right, the code is not entering the factory. One weird thing I noticed is that looking at the code after AoT compilation the constructor in the AppComponent "removes" the `Inject()`, so instead of `@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: any` I have `private appConfig: any`

Comment: Note sure if it's connected, but why do you have `any` type there? Why not use `AppConfig`?

Comment: Change ` useFactory: appConfigFactory()` ==> ` useFactory: appConfigFactory`

Comment: lol didn't see that in the updated question! yeah, you have to pass that function reference, not its return value.

Comment: haha damn I didn't realise, I'm half asleep :D thanks for your help kemsky and Martin :) it's working :)